# Software stack to allow clients to donate UI layouts and their own search queries to an Android app?

Tags: xml, jquery, sqlite, lua, android-app

I am creating a (potentially) mobile application in which the core functionality will provide opportunity to share client-created scripts and layouts (potentially yaml-based) to perform database queries and custom output forms from those.
What are the recommended file formats to achieve this? Will an Android app be able to execute those queries and scripts on the client side? Or is it better to defer script execution to some external web bot or maybe a microservice?

Comment: "Will an Android app be able to execute those queries and scripts on the client side?" - what/how large/where is your dataset? Will it be available entirely on the client side? You're going to have to run your queries where your dataset is located.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper the dataset is a relatively small (20 MB tops) group of files; the question was not about the technical possibility, it is about the software stack and preferrable file formats

Comment: I know, but you did ask whether you can execute the queries locally in the client. The answer to this question (and maybe also the eligible stacks and file formats) hinges directly on where your data is located, the options for which in turn directly depend on properties of the dataset.